# Database view taking too long time to fetch data when using order by clause

Tags: mysql, view, sql-order-by

I have created view which has more than 20 thousand records and executing a query on same view, its taking too long time to fetch only 20 records using limit.

If I removed ORDER BY clause then same query gives result within fraction of sec.

Even I tried that, applied order by condition on view so that I can execute query without ORDER BY clause but still query taking 1.1 min to 1.8 min to return result.

Here is the query :

```
SELECT full_name, project_no, customer_name, description, status, comments,
FROM (view_project)
WHERE labor_code IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 20
```

Definition of view :

select a.id AS id,a.tms_id AS tms_id,a.date AS date_from,a.hour AS hour,a.hour_ot AS hour_ot,a.hour_dt AS hour_dt,a.function AS function,a.billable AS billable,a.qb_class AS qb_class,a.comments AS comments,b.extra_fields AS extra_fields,a.labor_code AS labor_code,a.cost AS cost,a.bill AS bill,a.pr_cost AS pr_cost,a.pr_bill AS pr_bill,b.user_id AS user_id,b.date_from AS date_from_b,b.date_to AS date_to,c.full_name AS full_name,c.username AS username,d.name AS name,d.project_no AS project_no,d.id AS project_id,e.description AS description,f.name AS customer_name,concat(b.date_from,'|',b.date_to) AS week_range,a.data_row AS data_row,if((isnull(g.tms_row_status) or (g.tms_row_status = '')),'No Status',g.tms_row_status) AS status,ifnull(h.submit_entity,'') AS submit_entity,a.tms_row_uuid AS tms_row_uuid from (((((((labor_time_tracking a left join timesheet b on((a.tms_id = b.id))) left join user c on((b.user_id = c.id))) left join project d on((a.project_id = d.id))) left join supplier f on((d.customer_id = f.id))) left join item e on((convert(a.labor_code using utf8) = e.uuid))) left join labor_time_tracking_rows g on((a.tms_row_uuid = g.tms_row_uuid))) left join timesheet_submission h on(((a.tms_id = h.tms_id) and (a.project_id = h.project_id) and (a.data_row = h.tms_row_id)))) order by b.id desc

Comment: For such questions, you must add EXPLAIN of your query and A SHO'W CREATE TABLE for all involved tables

Comment: Please add the definition of the view, and the exact `ORDER BY` clause that is slow. It may be very simple to optimize.

Comment: Updated definition of view in question